# Does Qt Webkit with pyside and QML work with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pyside, qtwebkit

I am trying to use angularjs in a qt-webkit application with pyside bindings. It doesn't seem to work. Basic templates like

`{{2+3}}`

also do not work. I saw this. I saw this post on github

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2985

but didn't understand further implications of the limitations mentioned. Does this mean that any separately loaded js would not work because everything is pre-compiled.

Comment: I've run my angular application in a Qt webkit component of a bigger application with Qt 4.8.1 , 5.0.1 and 5.0.2. It does work but with several limitations, like bad JS performance or problems with the video tag. I haven't seen `qrc` anywhere but that might be due to local modifications.

Comment: If it's not running well from a Qt resource file you could just run it from the local filesystem. Just place the files in an application folder and open them from there. 

If you don't want them visible in your application folder you could place them in the `qrc` file and copy them over to a temporary directory when you need to. Open it from there and you have the same situation to work with.

I'm not sure if the problems are in the use of `qrc` files, but if it is this may be a simple solution.